# If $\sum a_n$ with $a_n>0$ is convergent, then is $\sum {a_n}^2$ and $\sum \sqrt{a_n}$ always convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

If $\sum a_n$ with $a_n>0$ is convergent, then is $\sum {a_n}^2$ and $\sum \sqrt{a_n}$ and $\sum \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ always  convergent? Either prove it or give a counter example.
 I am thinking that the second series is convergent by comparision test. because $$ \sqrt{a_n}\leq a_n$$

Comment: Hello! Can you please [edit] your question to include your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you're having trouble with? Do you know some examples of convergent / divergent series (e.g. $p$-series)? Do you know any convergence tests, like comparison?

Comment: yes.. the p series is cgt if p>1. and i know cmparision test also.. the problem is an>0.

Comment: Try comparing $a_n^2$ with $a_n$, then. Eventually, $a_n$ is small.

Comment: How do you know that $\sqrt{a_n} < a_n$? What happens if $a_n < 1$?

Comment: suppose $a_n<1$ I could conclude that $\sum a_n^2$ is convergent. But for other values...???

Comment: $\sum a_n$ converges implies it is bounded above by some $M$, so $\sum a_n^2$ is bounded above by $M \sum a_n$ and hence converges. $\sum \sqrt{a_n}$ need not converge. eg. $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$. Finally $\sum \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1} }$ is bounded above by $\frac12 \sum (a_n + a_{n+1})$ and hence converges.

Comment: oh.. suppose we have $a_n>1$ we can conclude all the series are convergent. Right?

Comment: If you have all $a_n > 1$, then the statement $\sum a_n$ converges is false.

Comment: oh.. i am sorry if $a_n>1$ the original one will not be convergent. understood. Thank you...

Comment: @achillehui how can we conclude that $\sum\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ is bounded by your bound. kindly give calculations...

Comment: apply $AM \ge GM$ to $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 7):

If $\sum\limits_n a_n$ is convergent, then $a_n <1$ for every $n >N$, hence $\sum\limits_na^2_n$ converges too. At the same time $\sum\limits_n\sqrt{a_n}$ need not be necessarily convergent. Take e.g. $a_n= \frac{1}{n^2}$.

EDIT thi is of course based on the fact that for $0<x<1$ of course $0 < x^2 < x <\sqrt{x}<1$.